# Combinatorics Reasoning

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So i was given a question that begins like this.

> How many ways are there to buy $10$ pieces of candy from an (unlimited)
>   supply of three kinds: jelly beans, chocolate almonds and skittles with at least $2$ candies of each kind.

I'm new to combinatorics so i'm really lost on how to solve this.

Comment: We are given no information about what kinds of jelly beans are available, so we are (unreasonably) expected to view them as indistinguishable. Grab $2$ of each kind of candy. Now we need to grab $4$, with no restriction. That's standard Stars and Bars, but is not hard to solve in other ways since $4$ is so small.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But where did the 4 come from, if we are dealing with 3 kinds of candy with at least 2 candies of each kind. And for the jelly beans it is just the jelly beans as one candy, not like different types of jelly beans

Comment: @André Nicolas So would the answer be 2 x 2 x 4?

Comment: The $4$ is the $4$ more candies we need to choose after we have grabbed $2$ of each kind: $2+2+2=6$, need to grab $4$ more to have $10$.

Comment: The answer is $15$, from the Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia) $\binom{6}{2}$. But we can do it in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

> How many ways are there to buy 10 pieces of candy from an (unlimited) supply of three kinds: jelly beans, chocolate almonds and skittles with at least 2 candies of each kind.

First buy two of each kind, then determine how many ways to buy the remaining four.

- Four of one kind: 3 ways:
- Three of one kind and one of another: $\binom 3{1}\binom 21$ ways
- Two of one kind and two of another: $\binom 32$ ways
- Two of one kind and one of each other: $\binom{3}{1}\binom 22$ ways

$$3+6+3+3=15$$

---

Using "stars and bars" we count ways to *arrange* four 'stars' and two 'bars' (to count ways to select four candies from three 'boxes'): $\binom {4+2}{4}=15$

Answer (score 0):

> Algebraic answer but one should be able to visualize

Call the chocolate types J, C and S. We will assume the chocolates get delivered in a bag without any inherent order.

Take a look at this (apparently unrelated) expression: 
 
${
(j^2+j^3+j^4+\ ...)
(c^2+c^3+c^4+\ ...)
(s^2+s^3+s^4+\ ...)
}$

assume that all the 3 vars are ${0<j,c,s<1}$

In the product, all the combinations of ${j,c,s}$ 
will appear which are of interest to us. They are those which look like these:

${j^p.c^q.s^r}$ 
such that

${2 \leq p,q,r\leq 6}$ 
and
 ${p+q+r=10}$

${p,q,r}$ cannot be more than 6, otherwise their sum cannot be 10.

The number of ways can be computed by substituting ${x}$ for each of ${j,c,s}$ in the above expression and calculating the coefficient of ${x^{10}}$.

The fact that these are infinite series do not matter, since any ${x^p}$ with ${p>6}$ will not contribute to ${x^{10}}$.

The expression becomes:

${(x^2+x^3+x^4+\ ...)^3\\
=x^6.(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ ...)^3\\
=x^6.(1-x)^{-3}\\
=x^6.(1+3x+\frac{3.4}{1.2}x^2+\frac{3.4.5}{1.2.3}x^3+\frac{3.4.5.6}{1.2.3.4}x^4+\ ...)\\
}$

The coefficient of ${x^{10}}$ is 
${\frac{3.4.5.6}{1.2.3.4}=15}$